# How can I access the DataContext via Project Dependency?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have setup a MVC 5 Solution that has two sub projects.  1) The MVC Application and 2) an API.

I am using EF 6 in the MVC Application, and I have set up a project dependency from the API to the MVC application.   However, when I try to use scaffolding in the API project, I get this error: "Unable to retrieve metadata for Chat.Message.  No connection string named "ChatEntities" could be found in the application config file.

Any advice on how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy connection string to the `web.config` file in `API` project.